# Exiting a Jython application that uses Swing

Tags: multithreading, jython

I'm using Swing from Jython, and I found that while `System.exit()` (from `java.lang`) or `JFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE)` work properly, calling `sys.exit()` hangs.

Apparently, a function is registered through `atexit.register` that waits for all threads to exit, as it is expected from Python (this is actually different from Java).

This means that if an `ActionListener` gets called (for instance when clicking on a `JButton`), AWT's Event Dispatching Thread gets spawned, and calling `sys.exit()` will hang forever, waiting for it to exit.

Here is an example: https://gist.github.com/2877919. Closing the frame exits the program, unless the button is clicked first.

What is the best way to exit my Jython application? Using `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` or `System.exit()` would completely ignore `atexit`...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need multithreading for this, you just need to make sure the window is not closed until you want so. When you close the window, you close the system:

```
from javax.swing import JFrame, JButton, JOptionPane
from java.awt.event import ActionListener, WindowAdapter
import sys

class Frame(JFrame, ActionListener):

    def __init__(self):
        self.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE)
        button = JButton("Hello", actionCommand='button')
        button.addActionListener(self)
        self.getContentPane().add(button)
        self.pack()
        self.setResizable(False)

    def actionPerformed(self, event):
        print event.getActionCommand();


class Adapter(WindowAdapter):
    def windowClosing(self, event):
        if JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(None, "Wanna exit?","Jython Test", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION) == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION:
            sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    frame = Frame();
    frame.setVisible(True)
    frame.addWindowListener(Adapter())
```

Comment: In your code the main thread returns, which allows you to terminate the application when you kill the EDT by throwing a `SystemExit`.
The problem is that when the main thread ends (by reaching the end of the file), the functions registered with `atexit` are executed... This is not what I want...

Comment: not only that but this code example violates rule no 1 of Swing re the EDT